# Blender Cycles rendering nothing

Tags: gpu, render, blender

When I try to render
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ3Xn.png)
scene: 
Blender render the image,but instead of showing meshes with their materials, it shows just a alpha image, so, nothing, like those objects weren't there:
I have a radeon R9 280X as gpu and AMd Athlon 750k as CPU.
The scene is set to Cycles render and the device is set to GPU Compute.
It has always worked in the right way, but since Windows 10 updated it stopped working.
Can these two things be linked?
Also,when i siwtch to Cpu as Device, it works properly.
And is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Cycles supports most rendering features using GPU rendering via CUDA for nVidia cards and some features using OpenCL for AMD video cards. As CPU rendering is working, either your OpenCL drivers need updating or you are trying to render with a feature that isn't supported in OpenCL.

A list of compatible features can be [found here](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/features.html) and you can find the R9 280x listed [on this page](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/OpenCL) as being compatible.

It may be that after updating windows you need to reinstall the AMD/OpenCL drivers or update them to a version compatible with windows 10.